# How to extract values from dynamic website using selenium and PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

i am trying to get the value for a timer >http://prntscr.com/kcbwd8
on this website > https://www.whenisthenextsteamsale.com/
and hopefully store it in a variable.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3"}

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get('https://www.whenisthenextsteamsale.com/')

soup = bs(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
result = soup.find_all("p",{"id":"subTimer"})

for item in result:
    print(item.text)

browser.quit()
```

i have tried using the code above but it returns this error >

> C:\Users\rober\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py:49:
>   UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated,
>   please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
>   warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated,
>   please use headless ' 19:59:11

is there any way to fix this ? if not is there another way to get the dynamic values of a site and store them in a variable.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJs is no longer being maintained.
https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/phantomjs/9aI5d-LDuNE

You should use headless chrome / firefox.

You will have to replace this code :

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get('https://www.whenisthenextsteamsale.com/')
```

**WITH**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
browser= webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path="Path to geckodriver.exe")
browser.get('https://www.whenisthenextsteamsale.com/');
```

Download Geckodriver here: [Download GeckoDriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Comment: do i have to change much to the code i currently have, if so what exactly ?

Comment: Yes! You need to change how are you creating  `browser` in existing code. I have already mentioned in answer, how can you call driver. This will replace `browser` creation. Rest all remains same.

Comment: I have updated my code. Hopefully it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just perfect. Though you havn't used the **headers** which you have defined as:

```
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3"}
```

I have executed your own script as follows:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3"}
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
browser.get('https://www.whenisthenextsteamsale.com/')
soup = bs(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
result = soup.find_all("p",{"id":"subTimer"})
for item in result:
    print(item.text)
browser.quit()
```

I do see the same output on the console as:

```
C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py:49: UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
  warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
08:06:16
```

It is worth to mention that the **Selenium** team have already dropped the default support for **PhantomJS** in *Selenium Java Client* and will follow the same with *Selenium Python Client*. The **warning** you are observing is part of the **`__init__()`** method of **PhantomJS** as follows:

```
def __init__(self, executable_path="phantomjs",
             port=0, desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS,
             service_args=None, service_log_path=None):
    """
    Creates a new instance of the PhantomJS / Ghostdriver.

    Starts the service and then creates new instance of the driver.

    :Args:
     - executable_path - path to the executable. If the default is used it assumes the executable is in the $PATH
     - port - port you would like the service to run, if left as 0, a free port will be found.
     - desired_capabilities: Dictionary object with non-browser specific
       capabilities only, such as "proxy" or "loggingPref".
     - service_args : A List of command line arguments to pass to PhantomJS
     - service_log_path: Path for phantomjs service to log to.
    """
    warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
                  'versions of Chrome or Firefox instead')
    self.service = Service(
        executable_path,
        port=port,
        service_args=service_args,
        log_path=service_log_path)
    self.service.start()
```